# Split on spaces not inside parentheses in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a several strings that I want to split by spaces when not inside parentheses.

For example

```
sentence = "blah (blah2 (blah3))|blah4 blah5"
```

should produce

```
["blah", "(blah2 (blah3))|blah4", "blah5"]
```

I've tried:

```
re.split(r"\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))", sentence)
```

but it produces:

```
['blah', '(blah2', '(blah3))|blah4', 'blah5']
```

Comment: Regular expressions cannot handle matching (nested) parentheses. It is one of the canonical examples that requires a context-free grammar.

Comment: Can there be an open or closing parentheses without a matching closing/open parentheses? Should this situation produce an error?

Comment: There can be. It should produce an error.

Comment: You really need to use a stack to maintain if you're inside brackets or outside. Once you've eliminated the stuff inside brackets, you can then use a regex split.

Comment: @ffledgling I don't think a stack is really needed, or at least maybe it's not called that. How about an integer to indicate depth?

Comment: @Optimus Do you mind if the spaces inside the brackets are removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's impossible to process that using regex because of parenthesis nesting.

An alternative would be some good old string processing with nesting count on parentheses:

```
def parenthesis_split(sentence,separator=" ",lparen="(",rparen=")"):
    nb_brackets=0
    sentence = sentence.strip(separator) # get rid of leading/trailing seps

    l=[0]
    for i,c in enumerate(sentence):
        if c==lparen:
            nb_brackets+=1
        elif c==rparen:
            nb_brackets-=1
        elif c==separator and nb_brackets==0:
            l.append(i)
        # handle malformed string
        if nb_brackets<0:
            raise Exception("Syntax error")

    l.append(len(sentence))
    # handle missing closing parentheses
    if nb_brackets>0:
        raise Exception("Syntax error")


    return([sentence[i:j].strip(separator) for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])])

print(parenthesis_split("blah (blah2 (blah3))|blah4 blah5"))
```

result:

```
['blah', '(blah2 (blah3))|blah4', 'blah5']
```

`l` contains the indexes of the string where a non-paren protected space occurs. In the end, generate the array by slicing the list.

note the `strip()` in the end to handle multiple separator occurrences, and at the start to remove leading/trailing separators which would create empty items in the returned list.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that the `re` module cannot handle recursion, the [PyPi `regex`  module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) can (to some extent). Just to show how advanced regex can work, here is the 2-regex approach: one validates the balanced parentheses and the second extracts the tokens:

```
>>> import regex
>>> sentence = "blah (blah2 (blah3))|blah4 blah5"
>>> reg_extract = regex.compile(r'(?:(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))|\S)+')
>>> reg_validate = regex.compile(r'^[^()]*(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\)[^()]*)+$')
>>> res = []
>>> if reg_validate.fullmatch(sentence):
    res = [x.group() for x in reg_extract.finditer(sentence)]

>>> print(res)
['blah', '(blah2 (blah3))|blah4', 'blah5']
```

*Extraction regex details*: matches 1 or more occurrences of

- `(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))` - Capturing group 1 matching either 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]+`) or (`|`) `(?1)` recurses the whole capturing group 1 pattern (recursion occurs)
- `|`  - or
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char

*Validation regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `\(` - opening `(` symbol
  - `(?>[^()]+|(?1))*` - 0+ occurrences of

    - `[^()]+` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - Subroutine call recursing Group 1 subpattern (recursion)
  - `\)` - a closing `)`
  - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)+`  - end of Group 1
- `$` - end of string